# Why $[E(K_q) : E_0(K_q)] ≤ 4$ and $E_0(K_q)$ is divisible by $2$ implies $E(K_q)[2^∞] = E[2]$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, local-field

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$ with no non-trivial rational $2$-torsion point.
We write $q$ for a odd prime of quadratic number field $K$. Let $K_q$ denote the $q$-adic completion of $K$. Suppose $dim_{\Bbb{F}_2}(E(\Bbb{Q}_{q})[2])=2$.

Lem 2.2. Page 3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10536.pdf reads

> Since $[E(K_q) : E_0(K_q)] ≤ 4$ and  $E_0(K_q)$ is **divisible by $2$**
> , $E(K_q)[2^∞] = E[2]$.

Why can we conclude　$E(K_q)[2^∞] = E[2]$  ? In these conditions, it seems there is no contradiction even if $E$ has order $4$ or $8$ element for me. I may have forgotten some basic group theory or elliptic curve theoretical results.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is assumed that $E(\Bbb{Q}_q)$ contains $E[2]$ and $q\ne 2$ so $E_0(K_q)$ is $2$-divisible. Also $E(K_q)[2^\infty]$ is finite.

Comment: Based on these materials, why can we conclude that $E(K_q)[2^∞]=E[2]$ ?

Comment: Maybe there is a terminology issue here? The author doesn’t mean that $\#E_0(K_q)$ is divisible by 2, but rather that $E_0(K_q)$ is 2-divisible. I.e. that for every $P$, there is a $Q$ with $2Q=P$. So if it has a 2-torsion point, it has a $2^n$-torsion point for all $n$.